# Source Insight is not displaying the full path of a file in the title bar

Tags: filepath, titlebar, source-insight

Consider that I have opened a file, `E:\code\module1\souce\temp.c`, in Source Insight. Then in the Source Insight title bar it will display the path as `temp.c(E:\code\..\source)`.

But I want it to display like `temp.c (E:\code\module1\source)`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Menu *Options* → *Preference* → *Display* → *Trim Long Path Names With ellipses*

Comment: Thanks but this still would not print the entire path. It may print something like temp.c(module1\source) since E:\code\ is the root.

Is there a way to print the entire temp.c(E:\code\module1\source) ?

Comment: @KingkongJnr It worked the way you want it for me doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is not available in Source Insight as of now in the free trial version.